# losing data when using php header()

Tags: php, session

My program is basically a form.  After the user presses the submit button, the program does input error checking (so I can't use the action element in form to call a new program).   After error checking I call another program using `header("Location: url")`.

The problem is I lose all my session data. I have `session_start()` as the first line in both programs, I use `$_SESSION['variable name']` to name some variables. My form uses the POST method.

My POST variables exist after the user presses submit but they are lost also after the `header()` call - along with my `$_SESSION['']` variables.  My session_id is the same for both programs. I have tried `session_write_close()` just before the `header()` statement - still lose the data.

How do I keep my variable data?

Comment: When you redirect, are you redirecting to the same domain? Same server?

Comment: Was about to ask the same question as FDL, are you sending to the exact same domain? www.mysite.com is different from mysite.com, cookies are not the same unless you override the domain path in the cookies which is rarely done!

Comment: _“My POST variables exist after the user presses submit but they are lost also after the header() call”_ – of course they are, because the client browser follows the redirect by issuing a _GET_ request for the new URL.

Comment: Code speaks louder than words. Please demonstrate the problem with the smallest amount of code necessary to reproduce it.

Comment: check `session_id()` in both scripts. if the value's changing, then you're getting a different session in each script, and you'll have to figure out why (probably a cookie setting problem).

Comment: Yes I am redirecting to the same domain.  The entire file path is the same, for both programs, except for the actual program name at the end of the file path.

Comment: Thanks Marc B.  Yes, the session_id() is the same when running both programs like I stated in my original post, "My session_id is the same for both programs".

Comment: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: <?php 
session_start();   <br/> 
function new_page(){   <br/>
header("Location: http://www.warnerreal.com/qw/sign_page.php");
die(); }
function error_handler(){
$GLOBALS[$no_errors] = "true";
if($_POST['fname']==""){
$GLOBALS[$no_errors] ="false";
}
}
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
error_handler();
if($GLOBALS[$no_errors] =="true"){
new_page();
}
}

>?

Comment: @CBroe:  Thanks for your comment.  You told me the problem but not how to fix it.  Maybe it is obvious to you.  I tried changing my program to use the GET method but I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Before you use your header, stock the content of your $_POST into a $_SESSION variable.
The $_POST variables aren't saved if you go from page 1 --> 2 --> 3, they are sent from page 1 to page 2, that's it.

Or 2nd option : when you do the header you can put the content of your post into the url to do something like :

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/index.php?name=".$_POST['name']);
```

And the when  after the header when you land on your page you can use :

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
```

And you'll get the name for instance.

edit : ty for fixing my english :)

Comment: My sentiments exactly. Plus, I edited `that it` to `that's it` but you re-edited back. I believe that's what you meant; least, that's how the expression goes ;)

Comment: Alex, I like your comment.  However, my form is dynamically generated and can have from 50 to 250 variables.  Your 2nd option looks good but the number of variables (and their names) changes with each user

Comment: Then you definately need to use the first one.
You can stock all the posted variables into a session variable which will be an array, it's possible :)

Comment: @Alex:  Thanks again.  But please note from my original comments that I lose my $_SESSION variables data also

Comment: All your pages have the extension .php and not .html right?

Comment: @Alex:  Right all have a .php extension

Answer (score 0):

When you assign those session variable .. try to echo them on the same page without the header and see it they are assigned properly.

and make sure your use exit() right after the header call. If you don't it still runs the rest of the script after redirecting you. it might be resetting the session variable since $_POST will be empty then.

let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks, MD.  Yes, I echoed all my variables - they exist.  And yes I use exit() after the header() call, I just didn't mention it in my original comments.